# Google Analytics programmatically simple login

Tags: c#, google-analytics-api, google-data-api

A question about security, using Google Data API to access the Google Analytics data.
I'm going to use this code on my site:

```
AnalyticsService asv = new AnalyticsService("");
asv.setUserCredentials(CLIENT_USERNAME, CLIENT_PASS);
```

Is it secure? Will username and password be send by plain text?
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

If you access Google Data API through https, your credentials will not be sent as plain text.

You can see Google's example here, check line 87 where the URL is defined:

https://code.google.com/p/ga-api-java-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/v2/DataFeedExample.java

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to my c# code for v3 of the api as part of that post answers [Automated use of google-api-dotnet-client with OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429392/automated-use-of-google-api-dotnet-client-with-oauth-2-0/12603329#12603329)